# using count to get the number of records in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch four records from two table.
Two takes some of the records and two takes count of the record.

```
SELECT sum( a.user_follower_count ) AS mention_reach, 
       count( a.sno ) AS mention_count, 
       sum( b.user_follower_count ) AS retweet_reach, 
       count( b.username ) AS count_retweet
FROM twitter_mention AS a, twitter_retweet AS b
```

Here mention_reach and retweet_reach are fetched correctly, but count values are comming wrong?
IS there anything wrong here?

I have only 6 records twitter_mention and 10 in twitter_retweet, but it gives 60 for both count values.

Comment: Unless you mention a join condition, the result would be a cross product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no JOIN between your tables `a` and `b`.

Add JOIN b ON

Or add explicit join in WHERE section

UPDATE

```
select *
from 
    (SELECT 
           sum( a.user_follower_count ) AS mention_reach, 
           count( a.sno ) AS mention_count 
    FROM twitter_mention AS a) a,
    (SELECT 
           sum( b.user_follower_count ) AS retweet_reach, 
           count( b.username ) AS count_retweet
    FROM twitter_retweet AS b) b
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate. i did not get

Comment: both table are independant, and result too

Comment: thanks, result are correct. I could not correct your answer bcoz still there is some time. C

Comment: here result comes in two rows. Is it possible in single row?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing a full join, which says.

For every record in table a, give me all records in table b.

```
 SELECT sum( a.user_follower_count ) AS mention_reach, 
           count( a.sno ) AS mention_count, 
           sum( b.user_follower_count ) AS retweet_reach, 
           count( b.username ) AS count_retweet
    FROM twitter_mention AS a, twitter_retweet AS b
```

What you need to do, is determine which record in table b you want for each record in table a, not all of them.   This is done via the ON clause on the join

```
 SELECT sum( a.user_follower_count ) AS mention_reach, 
           count( a.sno ) AS mention_count, 
           sum( b.user_follower_count ) AS retweet_reach, 
           count( b.username ) AS count_retweet
    FROM twitter_mention AS a
    JOIN twitter_retweet AS b   ON a.<somefield> = B.<somefield>
```

Also, you syntax for a JOIN should be updated to using the JOIN keyword.   You can see the JOIN syntax is my second query above.

If you don't have any common keys, I would recommend two queries using a UNION clause, i.e.

```
 SELECT 'MENTION' as Type,sum( a.user_follower_count ) AS reach, 
           count( a.sno ) AS count
    FROM twitter_mention AS a
 UNION
 SELECT 'RETWEET' as Type,sum( b.user_follower_count ) , 
           count( b.username ) 
 FROM twitter_retweet AS b
```

Comment: Thanks, but here a and b table are independant. They dont have any similar records